# MYSQL Choosing field's multiples values from a parameter's value

Tags: mysql, parameters, case, selection

(first message!).

I got a problem I don't know how to solve:

I got this select

```
select
p.id as pId, -- 0
p.code,
p.name 

from work_order as wo

left join project as p on wo.project_fk = p.id

where date(wo.date1) >= :initialDate
and date(wo.date1) <= :initialDate

group by p.id

order by p.code asc
```

I got a parameter (:state) with 3 possible values '1', '2' or '3' and a table's field (state_fk) with multiples values. I want that depending parameter's value to choose what values has state_fk. The next code is wrong but it can give you and idea of what I need:

```
select
p.id as pId, -- 0
p.code,
p.name 

from work_order as wo

left join project as p on wo.project_fk = p.id

where date(wo.date1) >= :initialDate
and date(wo.date1) <= :initialDate
and ( (case :state = '1' then ('abc', 'qwe') end) in state_fk 
    or (case :state = '2' then ('cdw', 'zxc', 'ere') end) in state_fk
    or (case :state = '3' then ('swq', 'bge', 'qah') end) in state_fk )

group by p.id

order by p.code asc
```

I'd be very grateful if someone tell me how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to do without a table definition so that we can test. But something like this should work:

```
select
p.id as pId, -- 0
p.code,
p.name 

from work_order as wo

left join project as p on wo.project_fk = p.id

where date(wo.date1) >= :initialDate
and date(wo.date1) <= :initialDate
and ( 
        (:state = '1' and state_fk in ('abc', 'qwe'))
        OR
        (:state = '2' and state_fk in ('cdw', 'zxc', 'ere'))
        OR
        (:state = '3' and state_fk in ('swq', 'bge', 'qah'))
    )

group by p.id

order by p.code asc
```

Comment: Oh my god, it's so ridiculously simple; much obliged!